# How to choose the Homebrew installation directory for LibreOffice?

Tags: libreoffice, homebrew

I do not want to install LibreOffice in `/Applications` but Homebrew insists on trying it, asking for permission via sudo.

How can I prevent brew from installing it?

(As background, I usually build my s/w but decided to go with Homebrew on my M1 because it does not muck about with root-owned directories -- until now.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent installation, I entered <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> at the sudo prompt. This left the application sitting in `./Caskroom/libreoffice/7.1.5` and I simply copied it to where I wanted.  (Another method is open another terminal and copy as above.)

I thought of this after posting my question -- sorry for the noise.

Comment: This is not a bad answer. Most people wouldn’t know that cutting off the process right at that point would allow the binary to be on the system but not installed in `/Applications/`. So nice job!

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Thank you for your comment and for your edits.

Comment: Also on M1.  I was not prompted for sudo, and app was saved in /Applications/